# Spring application context : access web.xml context-params?

Tags: java, spring, web.xml

Greetings ,

Is there any way to get values from web.xml context-param into Spring context?

For example I define the value in web.xml as :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>compass-index</param-name>
  <param-value>file:///home/compass/index</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And I want to assign that value to the bean-property as:

```
<bean ...>
<props>
  <prop key="compass.engine.connection">
    ${from web.xml context-param?}
  </prop>
</props>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes - [`ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

[This article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2008/04/25/configuring-applications-with-spring/) explains the details. In short, you need:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
</bean>
```

and then use the properties like:

```
<bean ...>
   <property name="compassIndex" value="${compass-index}" />
</bean>
```

or with `@Value("${compass-index}")`

Comment: As of Spring 3.1 class ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is deprecated (see javadocs for details).

Comment: Thanks. So look at the deprecation instructions at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Comment: Especially "cool" feature in spring docs is the fact that deprecation has been mentioned, but no updated sample code has been provided.

Comment: @Askar Kalkov The documentation is not very clear on what you have to do, but in the end it's actually quite simple. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21175824/1669464

Comment: This seems like the correct XML since ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer was deprecated:  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="environment"><bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment" /></property>
 </bean>