# How to add context parameter after loading spring context

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to add a servlet context parameter/attribute through spring configuration. I need this because the value I want to add in servlet context is available only after spring container loads. I'm adding the value inside the servlet context as I need the value in almost all my .jsp files.

Essentially I need a mechanism opposite to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175502/spring-application-context-access-web-xml-context-params)

Comment: You can't add servlet context parameters programmatically, there's no API for that. Why can't your Spring controllers just add the values to the model before forwarding to the view?

Comment: Actually, you can... check out the javadocs for ServletContext, namely setAttribute(String,Object).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using a properly configured Spring Web Application Context, you could try implementing a bean that implements org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware and org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean so that you could add whatever you want to the ServletContext in the afterPropertiesSet method implementation.

```
public class ServletContextInjector implements ServletContextAware,InitializingBean {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext sc){ this.servletContext = sc; }

    public void afterPropertiesSet(){
        servletContext.setAttribute( /* whatever */ );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.