# Spring MVC 3 getInitParameter

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

When I previously developed servlet applications without Spring, I could read configuration parameters like this in my servlet:

```
@Override public void init() throws ServletException { 

    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    String someSetting = sc.getInitParameter("someSetting");

}
```

However, I'm developing an application with Spring MVC now, which means I no longer have a servlet myself, but use Spring's `DispatcherServlet`.

Now, how can I access those init parameters in `spring-servlet.xml` to pass them to one of my beans?

I'm using Spring 3, and am a n00b with it. Every time I see a bean without an id, my mind flips XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can `@Inject` a `ServletContext` in your controllers, and take the params from there.

Of better, use `@Value` together with a specific`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175502/spring-application-context-access-web-xml-context-params)

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion: I know how to inject the `ServletContext` once I have a reference to it, but where do I get that?

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom you inject it (with `@Inject` or `@Autowired`). Spring takes care of fetching it, not you.

Comment: Yeah I'm using @Inject now and it works. It's a bit voodoo'ish, but good for now :p

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need these to be init-parameters in the Servlet context?

In Spring you can just inject values into your beans from a properties file using [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).

Comment: Yes, they should come from the servlet context because that's the only place to inject local configuration data without putting it inside the webapp. Even if I put all configuration in a properties file, I'd need to insert the location of that file with an init-parameter, which I can specify in Tomcat's context file for this app.

Comment: a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is configured in your Spring context files, with a path to a file that is usually loaded from the classpath. You then inject values into other beans with references like `<property name="foo" value=${foo}"/>`.

Comment: Yes I know, but I can't put configuration in the classpath, because that means putting it inside the webapp's root directory, which should be a black box to the deployer (and also brings pain when you have multiple instance of the app, such as for testing and live).

Comment: loading from the classpath is merely one option, you could also load from any absolute path in the filesystem. Regardless, the advantage of using propertyPlaceholders are merely injecting values into your Spring beans is that the classes can remain ignorant of the Servlet environment - the same class can be re-used a-okay in non-webapps.

Comment: An absolute path isn't much better, so the path must be passed in from the outside. Init params are perfect for that. I do agree about the advantage of injecting though, which is why I've wrapped the servlet context in a `Config` class.