# Reading tomcat context xml param value in Spring Junit

Tags: spring, tomcat, junit

I need help to load/inject tomcat/conf/catalina/localhost/myapp.xml in my SpringJunit Test. I am testing my mail service from JUnit.

Mail Spring XML:

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="#{contextParameters.mail_host}"/>
    <property name="username" value="#{contextParameters.mail_username}" />
    <property name="password" value="#{contextParameters.mail_password}" />
    <property name="port" value="#{contextParameters.mail_port}" />
    ....
```

Tomcat MyApp.xml:

```
    <Context reloadable="true">  
    <Parameter name="mail_host" value="XXXXX" override="true"/>
    <Parameter name="mail_username" value="XXXXXX" override="true"/>
    ....
```

I need to inject my mail details from tomcat myapp.xml in spring-mail.xml. I can able to load my spring context properties and beans but not tomcat parameters. Help appreciated!.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2175518/696632) should work for you. Try it out.

Comment: If I run in web container , it works great. But I need to load context-params from JUnit Test

Comment: You need to mock JNDI then.